# Problema al tratar de iniciar mysql de xampp

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp

Al iniciar xampp, todo inicia correctamente, pero al intentar ingresar mysql así:

```
/opt/lampp/bin$ mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

Me aparece esto:

> El programa «mysql» puede encontrarse en los siguientes paquetes:
>
> - mysql-client-core-5.7
> - mariadb-client-core-10.0
>   Intente: sudo apt install

Si voy a phpmyadmin, si puedo crear bases de datos y todo. Antes funcionaba por consola, pero ahora no.

Comment: Actualizaste el programa hace poco?

Comment: @Huskie no,pero intente intalar mysql workbench y se apago el equipo,puede haber sido por eso?no se como buscar si quedaron rastros de esa instalacion

Comment: ya probe reintalando xampp y no funciona,tampoco tengo el workbeanch

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas a mysql agregado a tu path del sistema? Es raro porque al instalar se agrega automáticamente

Comment: si era  la variable de entorno no estaba agregado ,muchas gracias

Comment: De nada me alegra que ha sido útil. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando sucede lo que comentas normalmente es por una de estas dos situaciones:

**1)** La instalación del programa ha quedado corrupta: Sucede por algún motivo la instalación no se completó correctamente (la interrumpiste manualmente, el internet es inestable si es online, se fue la energía eléctrica mientras se instalaba, entre otros). Entonces cuando Linux intenta encontrar la información necesaria para ejecutar al comando `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` no logra completar el chequeo y por tanto arroja un error como el que muestras en tu descripción.

**Solución:** Desinstalar completamente el programa e instalarlo nuevamente

**2)** Puede que la ruta del programa no esté agregada a la variable de entorno **PATH**: En casos muy poco frecuentes puede suceder que el sistema no agregó automáticamente la ruta del ejecutable del programa recien instalado a la variable **PATH**. Al no estar agregado a la variable **PATH** no puedes ejecutarlo correctamente desde cualquier directorio desde la terminal y si lo intentas obtienes un error como el que muestras en tu descripción.

**Solución:** Debes agregar la ruta del nuevo programa en tu variable **PATH** para que pueda ser accedido globalmente desde cualquier directorio en la terminal.

En tu caso: `path export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/`

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Answer (score -1):

simplemente se añade a la variable path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/
```

Comment: perdon no supe como marcarla,porque es un comentario no una respuesta y soy nuevo aqui,busque y no encontre como marcarlo como solucionando

Comment: Es que estaba por agregarla como respuesta pero se me fue el internet xD. No te preocupes me alegra que ha sido útil y lo importante es que quedó también como colaboración a la comunidad. Cualquier pregunta no dudes en hacerla que si puedo te sigo colaborando! Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor no le puntuen negativamente sin explicarle el por qué. Es un usuario nuevo, evitemos desmotivarlos. No es que no puntuen es que expliquen por qué así el usuario nuevo se percata de su error y lo corrige!